# Jenkins won't send e-mails anymore

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp

This might be a tough thing to figure out but i have to give it a try.

With no changes i am aware of, my jenkins just stopped sending out e-mail notifications. I use jenkins 1.609 and email extension plugin 2.40.5. Jenkins runs as a service using a service user who also has the rights on the server to send e-mails. Ports to our smtp-server are unlocked. Used telnet for testing that everything works as expected. SMTP-server works fine, so it has something to do with jenkins and i cant figure out what is going wrong.

For some unknown reason jenkins still fails to send e-mails. When i use the test-feature that jenkins offers i get: `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful` which tells me that either user or pw is incorrect, but as mentioned i've checked many times, it's setup correctly. Can anyone help out with this?

**UPDATE:**

After decrypting the password i can safely say that jenkins does save the password correct. Is there any way i can check that jenkins actually compares the correct encrypted passwords with each other? From my understanding jenkins uses 2 different encrypting techniques, maybe it uses tech1 for stored pw and tech2 for compare pw?

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

Just tried adding a new certificate to the keystore, just in case, still no change.

**MORE UPDATES:**

Tried updating the mailer plugin- no change

Tried different users - all failed with the same error

So no matter what user i try, they all fail, but have jenkins execute a script which sends e-mails using said users it works.

August 18, 2016 - no change

Comment: Has the user/pw expired or been locked perhaps?

Comment: No. Pw is set to not expire, because of reasons like this. Checked anyway, but its working as intended.

Comment: Maybe try checking under "Manage Jenkins -> configure" your smtp configuration - and make sure you still have the right information there.

Comment: @Dvir669 that information is still correct, triple-checked just to rule out even the dumbest reasons for jenkins to fail

Comment: If I were in your shoes I would write a quick script that uses smtp library with the same configuration as your Jenkins to send a simple email to me. it's 15 minutes work to eliminate the "Jenkins" factor - see that you actually able to send emails using your user and smtp settings regardless of Jenkins....... Good luck, if I'll think of anything else I'll add another comment :)

Comment: @Dvir669 i tried that yesterday, just to rule out even more possibilities. And what can i say: it works fine. Its definitly something that is related to jenkins. Please keep the ideas coming :) and also check out the update i provided in the original post!

Comment: Ok, I have a stupid idea but it's worth trying - can you try reset your password in Jenkins? meaning, go to configure, remove check from "Use SMTP Authentication" and save. then go to configure again and re-add the credentials. nothing better than "unplug and re plug" tactic :)

Comment: @Dvir669 i tried that, still no change. I also tried something, installed powershell-Plugin and made a test project in jenkins. First i run a powershell script to send me an e-mail via jenkins with user and pw hardcoded in it. Then afterwards it sends an e-mail using the mail-notifications provided by jenkins. Powershell script sends out without any problems, jenkins mail fails. The more stuff i try the more i am certain that jenkins just saves an incorrect password. is there any way i can see the unprotected password that jenkins has saved for e-mail notification?

Comment: If you're using the Email extension plugin, you have a configuration file called : hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml under $Jenkins_Home (where your config.xml is). if you're using the regular built in Jenkins emails it should be in your config.xml in Jenkins, although I'm not sure and I have to check that. give it a try and when I'll get back to work I'll check it for you :)